# Metric Conversion Calculator in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

Does anyone know how to take a numeric entry and put it through a formula?
I'm trying to create a conversion calculator for millimeters to inches, with a switch that changes the formula so you can calculate inches to millimeters.
so far, this is what i have done, and I'm using xcode 3.2.6

.m

```
@synthesize entry;
@synthesize output;
@synthesize toggle;

//-(IBAction)hidekeyboard:(id)sender{

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    float floatoutput=[entry.text floatValue]/[25.4];
}
```

.h

```
    IBOutlet UITextField *entry;
    IBOutlet UILabel *output;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *toggle;
}

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hidekeyboard:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *entry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *output;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISwitch *toggle;
```

I'm very new to xcode and any information you could give me would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
- (float)conver2inches: (NSString *)mmeters {
    return [mmeters floatValue]/25.4f;
}

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    float answer = [self conver2inches:entry.text];
    textfield1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",answer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong :

It should be as :

```
float floatoutput=[entry.text floatValue]/25.4;
```

`[ ]` is used for method calls or for subscripting of array. You need not write `[25.4]` which makes no-sense.

**And make a note 25.4 is not `float`, it is `double` you should use `25.4f`*

Comment: thank you for the information on where to use brackets, and how to use floats